# Looking for a way for clients to upload files, need obfuscated links on front-end and need to group files with headings

Tags: assets, file-uploads

I've used Channel Files(DevDemon) field to upload files and list them with obfuscated links on the front end successfully. But on a new site I need to group files and give them headings. Channel Files allows grouping by category, but the client can't add categories on the fly.

I need to display the files on the front end similar to this...

[image]

Any ideas on how I can do this? Will the Assets plugin allow me to do this? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Would it work if the hierarchy was based on the folder and file structure itself, Mike?

Comment: Possibly, but it seems like letting the client manage folders could be tough. Can you upload and mange folders within the field on the publish form?

Comment: Well, you could use Assets for this, which will handle subfolders in 2.1 (it doesn't quite yet, but will soon.)  you can create folders via the Assets module page as well, so they could manage it without FTP access.  Not through the publish form, however - they'd need to use the Assets CP page from Modules > Assets.  You'd still need something to obfuscate the links though. :)

Comment: Lisa, thanks for your help. I'm considering maybe using an Assets field in a Matrix column so each row could be a file "group" with a heading. The site is on EE v2.1.3 and it's part of a 3-site MSM install of EE. Do you think I will have any problems with installing and using Matrix and Assets? Does Assets also work with file upload folders above root?

Comment: Mike, you'll definitely need to upgrade EE to use the latest versions of Matrix and Assets.  Assets' local sources are from the file upload preferences in EE, so you can set a path above root in those preferences.  No problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you don't need all of that functionality in a single add-on, you can obfuscate your links (and track the downloads, etc) using [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault), which pretty much works with any file field.

Comment: Ryan, I might use the Assets field in a Matrix column. Will Link Vault be able to work with these plugins and encrypt the file download links?

Comment: Mike, Link Vault works with Assets in a Matrix row just fine. Here is an example : [link](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/link-vault/viewthread/8526#28991)